# postgresql error after installing : connection to server failed

Tags: sql, postgresql, ubuntu

I've installed postgresql on Ubuntu 21.04.

when I want to use it with `psql` command I got this error:

```
psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432" failed: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?
```

**update 1**

I had postgres before. today I tried to use it and I got this error, so I remove everything about postgres using `sudo apt remove postgresql-13 postgresql-client-13 postgresql-client-common postgresql-14 postgresql-client-14 postgresql-common` and installed postgres by `sudo apt install postgresql` .

in tutorials, they install postgres and start using it without any configurations but I can't do that.

---

**update 2**

output of `pg_lsclusters` command:

```
Ver Cluster Port Status                Owner    Data directory              Log file
13  main    5432 down,binaries_missing postgres /var/lib/postgresql/13/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-13-main.log
14  main    5433 online                postgres /var/lib/postgresql/14/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-14-main.log
```

Comment: The error message is specific: ' Is the server running locally and accepting connections on that socket?`. So did you start the server? In `postgresql.conf` is `port` set to `5432`? Further information: How did you install Postgres? Do you have more then one instance of Postgres running? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: What does `pg_lsclusters` show? Add as update to your question.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Updated.

Comment: The output is pretty clear, the Postgres server that is up is listening on port `5433`. The one that is set up for port `5432` does not have binaries installed. Your choices are `psql  -p 5433`,  install the Postgres 14 binaries or change the Postgres 13 server to listen on port `5432`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver When I run `psql -p 5433` command I got this error: `psql: error: connection to server on socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5433" failed: FATAL:  role "smjt2000" does not exist
`. how I can change the Postgres 13 port to 5432 ?

Comment: Again the  message is clear, the database cluster does not have the role `smjt2000`. Best guess is because you are starting with a new cluster and have not populated the databases and the global(roles) information yet. Try `psql -p 5433 -U postgres`. Messages are there to help you, they will for the most part tell you what the issue is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit this files for solve port problem:

`/etc/postgresql/14/main/postgresql.conf` :

`port = 5433`  ->  `port = 5432`

`/etc/postgresql/13/main/postgresql.conf` :

`port = 5432`  ->  `port = 5433`

---

Open `/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf` with your preferred editor and change the following line:

```
local     all     postgres               peer
```

to this:

```
local     all     postgres               trust
```

then run `sudo service postgresql restart`

run `psql -U postgres` and run this command:

```
ALTER USER postgres WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD "#your-password" ;
CRETE USER smjt2000 WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD "#your-password" ;
CREATE DATABASE smjt2000 OWNER smjt2000 ;
```

exit the postgresql shell by entering `exit`

change `/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf` to this:

```
local     all     postgres          md5
```

finally run `sudo service postgresql restart`

Comment: It's good but when I run `psql` it doesn't ask my password.

Comment: @mohammadjavad open `/etc/postgresql/14/main/pg_hba.conf` and change this line `local     all     all        peer` to `local     all     all        md5`

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if postrgresql service is running. It could be in an inactive state.

```
○ postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: **inactive (dead)**
```

To check the **status** of the service:

```
$sudo service postrgresql status
```

Your error is as a result of the service being inactive, hence not part of the local connection. To restart the service:

```
$sudo service postrgresql restart
```

Confirm if it is active:

```
$sudo service postrgresql status

● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
 Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
 Active: active (exited) since Tue 2022-01-18 02:13:35 EST; 2min 16s ago
Process: 167135 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 167135 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    CPU: 3ms
```